# Export a diagram drawn using applet and graphics as pdf

Tags: java, pdf, graphics, applet, 2d

My requirement is to draw a graph using a co-ordinate system which I am currently doing using java applets and AWT graphics package. I need to export the diagram drawn as a pdf file? Is there anyway to do it using the graphics package itself or is there any other way out. I am using the following code to create the diagram

```
public class Draw extends Applet{

        public void paint(Graphics g){
               g.drawRect(10,10,50,100);
               g.drawRect(100,100,50,50);
        }
}
```

Can the output of this code be saved as a pdf? Additionally can the scale for Graphics2D be set to mm instead of pixels? I am not sure if manual conversion is good enough, because extreme precision would be necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=252) example.

Comment: You should have a look at `JFreeChart` and `iText`. That's the route I'd go

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Works perfectly! Thanks a lot. You should post it as an answer so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: I have added another small addition to the question "can the scale for Graphics2D be set to mm instead of pixels".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the iText [com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/awt/PdfGraphics2D.html) as in [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=252) from Chapter 14 of "iText in Action".

Comment: Can the scale for Graphics2D be set to mm instead of pixels?

Comment: You'll need an [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html), this [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/commons/trunk/src/java/org/apache/xmlgraphics/util/UnitConv.java?p=820841) may help - and remember there are 72 dots per inch on your screen (and 300 dots per inch in a high quality PDF - about 118 dots per cm).

Comment: What exactly is this resolution parameter  return mm2in(mm) * resolution; What should be used for a high resolution pdf? Moreover g.drawRect(10,10,50,100); only accepts integers isn't it?

Comment: You don't do the conversion, you pass in a scaling AffineTransform of [TYPE_UNIFORM_SCALE](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/affine.htm) or of type TYPE_GENERAL_SCALE, to do the conversion.

Comment: Is there any working example of converting a straight line from co-ordinates to mm?

Comment: Try [these](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.geom.AffineTransform).